# How to continue to read a binary file with .read?

Tags: c++, loops, file-io, binary

I'm trying to read a binary file that contains a 1501-by-1501 matrix of double, and plug it in an Eigen matrix. Here is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
    MatrixXd B(1501, 1501);
    ifstream inputFile;

    double toread;

    inputFile.open("/path/to/bathymetry_S1000s2500s_E65d1000s65d2500s.bin",
                   ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!inputFile) {
        cout << "The file can't be opened.\n";
        exit(10);
    } else {    
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 1501; i2++) {
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 1501; i1++) {
                inputFile.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>( &toread ),
                                sizeof(toread) );
                inputFile >> toread;
                B(i1, i2) = toread;
            }

        }
        inputFile.close();
    }

    cout << "Max value:" << B.maxCoeff() << endl; // Just to check the result
    cout << "Mean Value:" << B.mean() << endl; // The same
}
```

My problem is that, when I run the code, my matrix B is actually filled only with the very first value of the inputFile, which is -4502, which will then be given by the two cout. (All the elements of the matrix are -4502). How can I make the compiler understand that I want it to continue reading the inputFile after the previous value, instead of starting from the beginning at each loop-step?

Comment: Wat is `inputFile >> toread;` for? (Don't mix formatted and unformatted input)

Comment: You're not checking the result of the `inputFile.read()` call

Comment: The inputFile >> toread is there to plug the recently read value into a double variable that I then plug into my matrix B. How would you do that otherwise?

Comment: Since I didn't get any compilation errors and something is coming from the reading of the file, I didn't think about checking the result of the inputFile.read() call. I think the problem is not wether or not it reads, the problem is about how it reads.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answer, the mistake has been found. Removing the inputFile>>toread line, everything works fine. I did copy/paste that part of the code, and it obviously wasn't a good idea.